# Create actions from buttons in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I want to create an action for a button I have stored within a UITableViewController, I have the code for the action already but I am unsure how to achieve this?

I have tried to ctrl drag to the ViewController.swift file but it does not allow me to create any actions or outlets. This is probably as it is not in the same class, but when I try to change its class to that it does not allow me to either.

Update of what I can see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it's a static tableView you should be able to make a method on the controller class with the prefix @IBAction func and be able to hook it up to the button by accessing the outlets and actions pane of the controller in Interface Builder.

I made a quick project and took a photo of it so you could see what i'm talking about
[image: interface builder image]

If it's a dynamic table then you would probably build out the custom tableView cell and take care of the display there.  To get the action functioning you could use a delegate on the cell and call the delegate method on press

Comment: It wont let me connect the action to the button :( Thats the issue still

Comment: @JamesPatterson added a photo to help explain. if it won't let you do then something else might be going on

Comment: Hmm, I don't have the received actions section on mine. I updated my question with a picture to show what my screen looks like

Comment: You have to create the method with the prefix @IBAction and also make sure that the class is linked to the interface builder file

Comment: How do I make sure it is linked to the interface builder file? Thanks for your replies

Comment: In the same right hand side pane the 2nd menu option from the left, make sure class name is the name of your controller

Answer (score 0):

First you need a Controller.swift file of type UITableViewController which will be assigned to your UITableViewController storyboard element (your table).

```
class Controller: UITableViewController {

    @IBAction func tapTheButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    }

}
```

Assign the "tapTheButton" function to the "Touch Up Inside" Send Event of your Button.

[image: Needed elements]

Comment: So I just create a new swift file with the code you listed, then insert the action into there for the button?

Comment: Tried to do this, it allows me to create the action just fine but when I try to press the button the app crashes. It doesn't give me an error line either :(

Comment: Yes, create a new .swift file subclass of UITableViewController and assign that file to your UITableViewController located in your storyboard.

Comment: Yes I did this but still no luck, the app crashes when I press the button. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: This is another problem. Please add a "NSLog("test");" in that function to see if the function is executed.

Comment: Have you created a Prototype Cell subclass of UITableViewCell? Do you have a dynamic table or a static table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105502/discussion-between-james-patterson-and-alin-golumbeanu).